# Project Euler Q #3 Python

Tags: python

I'm really trying to improve my math/coding/problem solving skills by working through the Project Euler problems, and I'm a little stuck on question three. The question is "The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29. What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?"

And here's my code thus far

```
import math

def isPrime(n):
   if n > 1:
     for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
   else:
     return False

def highFactor(m):
   factors = []
   for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(m))):
     if isPrime(i):
        if m % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
   print max(factors)

highFactor(13195)
```

So this obviously was testing on the example they gave since I already know the answer should be 29, but when I run the code it gives me 91. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your `isPrime` function returns true too early.

Comment: You might want to look up a better algorithm for prime checking.

Comment: For debugging, it might help to check your code with a lower number first and print out intermediate results.

Comment: note that you only have to loop over `2 <= i^2 <= n`, which is a significant speed up of your algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your function returns True too early - e.g. if a number is not divisble by 2, it does not mean it will not be divisible by any later number in the range(2, n) - consider 51 = 3 * 17 as a counter-example.

Here is the correct version of your algorithm:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(2, n):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
       return True
    else:  # if we have a negative number or 0
       return False
```

As others mentioned, there is a faster way to check whether a number is prime; now your function has complexity of `O(n)`, since you check for all numbers up to n; by observation that `n = sqrt(n) * sqrt(n)` it is enough to check until `sqrt(n) + 1`

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Careful with where you put your `return`. `isPrime(-4)` would return `True`

Comment: @A.Campbell: thanks, I fixed my answer; I did the question beforehand so I know you are given a positive number to compute its biggest factor.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

(1) Your isPrime function returns True on the first iteration of the loop.  You instead want to finish looping and then return True if you survive the entire loop without ever returning false.

(2) It's possible that an algorithm will have multiple copies of the same prime factor (ie 8 = 2*2*2).  You would be better off setting m = m/i and restarting the loop every time. Also, you probably want sqrt(m)+1, since the range function excludes the upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

As Austin commented `isPrime` returns true too early. By moving `return True` outside of the `for` loop your function will check each number in `range(2, n)` before confirming that the number is prime.

Say you were to do `isPrime(13)` which should return `True`

On the first pass of the `for` loop `if n % i == 0` would be `if 13 % 2 == 0` which is False. Because of the `else: return True` in the `for` loop the function will return `True` and terminate.

To solve the issue you could write `isPrime()` like:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(2, n):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False
```